# Filter by field customizer column

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, fieldcustomizers

I have an SPFx field application customizer that renders some custom text in a column. The column is created with a feature in the extension.

Is it possible to filter on that text in the list later on? I tried to create a view and filter on text not blank on the custom column but that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPFx Field Customizers only provides *modified views* for fields within a list and those are client-side components that run inside the context of a SharePoint page.

So, as per my understanding filters will not work on the field as you mentioned as it does not store/modify column value in list (at backend).